# Django async model update not being enacted

Tags: django, sqlite, asynchronous, django-models, django-channels

The SQL update does not seem to be being enacted upon, and no errors are being thrown either. Below is a simplified version of my code. For context, the "choice" field in the model is a Boolean Field with a default of False, and a user may (ideally) change this by sending a JSON package with the "CHOICE" event and "Yes" message.

**consumers.py**

```
import json
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer
from asgiref.sync import sync_to_async
from .models import Room

class Consumer(AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        self.room_code = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['room_code']
        #Websockets connection code
    async def disconnect(self):
        #Websockets disconnect code
    async def receive(self, text_data):
        response = json.loads(text_data)
        event = response.get("event", None)
        message = response.get("message", None)
        if event == "CHOICE":
            room_set = await sync_to_async(Room.objects.filter)(room_code=self.room_code)
            room = await sync_to_async(room_set.first)()
            if (not room.choice) and message["choice"] == 'Yes':
                sync_to_async(room_set.update)(choice=True) #line seems to not be working
            elif room.choice and message["choice"] == 'No':
                sync_to_async(room_set.update)(choice=False)
            #code to send message to group over Websockets
        #code regarding other events
    async def send_message(self, res):
        #Websockets send message code
```

I've tried to only include the relevant code here, but if more is needed please let me know. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by adding `await` before the `sync_to_async(room.update)(choice=True)` lines. It seems without an `await` it will move onto the next line of code before completing the SQL update, causing the update to not go through.